# Finding a (sort of parent) id

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In the following code :

```
<div class="dropdown">
                <a href="/Activites" id="menu_item_activites">
                  <span><i class="icon-svg_3_activite"></i>Activités
                  </span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="/Coloriage">Coloriages</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Activites/Cuisine">Cuisine</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Activites/Boutique">Boutique</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

When clicking on the "Coloriages" link, I would like to retrieve the closest id above, so "menu_item_activites" or the text.

I tried numerous things including :
var x = $(this).closest("span").text();
alert(x);

but that return me an empty alert?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. the `return false;` is only there so that the snippet below doesn't 404 :)

```js
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function() {
  var x = $(this).parents("div").find("a").attr("id");
  console.log(x);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="/Activites" id="menu_item_activites">
    <span><i class="icon-svg_3_activite"></i>Activités
                  </span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="/Coloriage">Coloriages</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Activites/Cuisine">Cuisine</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Activites/Boutique">Boutique</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may select the element **dropdown** and then the children anchor:

```js
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var x = $(this).closest('.dropdown').children('a');
      console.log('ID: ' + x.attr('id') + ' text: ' + x.text().trim());
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="/Activites" id="menu_item_activites">
                  <span><i class="icon-svg_3_activite"></i>Activités
                  </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="/Coloriage">Coloriages</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Activites/Cuisine">Cuisine</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Activites/Boutique">Boutique</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, Gaetano,
Thanks a lot. That's the solution I decided to go to!

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the exact code below,**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).closest('.dropdown-menu').prev().attr('id'));
   });
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="dropdown">
 <a href="/Activites" id="menu_item_activites">
  <span><i class="icon-svg_3_activite"></i>Activités
  </span>
 </a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="/Coloriage">Coloriages</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Activites/Cuisine">Cuisine</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Activites/Boutique">Boutique</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And rest of you can modify it according to your need.